# NetTcpBinding on Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-7.1

Now that Mango supports sockets, is it possible to create WCF NetTcpBindings? Currently the class is not included in System.ServiceModel.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had a look at the MS documentation on the new APIs in Silverlight for Mango:

[New Silverlight APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237343%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)

And there are no changes to the System.SereviceModel namespace, so I suspect the answer is no.  This was only added to Silverlight 4.0, and even then, silverlight 4.0 needed to have the netTcpBinding security mode set to "None" for it to work.

Silverlight for Windows Phone is based on Silvrlight 3.0.